# Increase input field by clicking button in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I have text input from SharePoint list,

what I want to do is when the user Click on the + icon increase the text field by 1

[image]

this code is OnSelect for the plus Icon

```
Value(DataCardValue53.Text)+1
```

Comment: so what is the problem? is it not working giving any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this:

1. Write below formula in `OnVisible` property of Screen control:

```
UpdateContext({txtInputVal: 0});
```

2. Set `OnSelect` property of button control to:

```
UpdateContext({txtInputVal: Value(DataCardValue53.Text) + 1})
```

OR

```
UpdateContext({txtInputVal: txtInputVal + 1})
```

3. Set `Default` property of text box (`DataCardValue53`) control to:

```
txtInputVal
```

**Documentation**: [Understand variables in canvas apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/working-with-variables)